# How to implement progressable image upload in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms app in which image is uploaded to server. I would like to show progress bar on UI. I am trying to create it with [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/199379/#Comment_199379) reference. I created class ProgressableStreamContent:

```cs
public class ProgressableStreamContent : HttpContent
{
    public ProgressableStreamContent(HttpContent content, Action<int> progress)
    {...}

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {...}
}
```

Problem is in parameter of SerializeToStreamAsync procedure where TransportContext is not recognized as class. Error message is: "The type or namespace name 'TransportContext' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?". When I navigate to HttpContent, there is:

```cs
public abstract class HttpContent : IDisposable
{
    ...
    protected abstract Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, Net.TransportContext context);
}
```

So it is not writen TransportContext, but Net.TransportContext. Does it mean that it is internal? How can I use this class in my code? I tried to put System.Net.TransportContext without success.

Comment: According to [the .NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.transportcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) it is not internal, and also usable in a portable class library. It is contained within the `System` assembly. Did you get the same error message when you added the full namespace like `System.Net.TransportContext`? What is the Target Framework (profile) you have set?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed Microsoft.Net.Http Nuget Package. Now it is compiling correctly. How can I delete question?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question. Other users might be helped by this in the future. What I'm still finding odd, is that I didn't have to install this NuGet package to get this working as long as I used the correct Target Framework (78 or 111 for example).

Comment: I don't know which target framework am I using. How can I check that?

Comment: On Xamarin Studio: Go to your project options, under the `General` tab you can find it under `Target Framework`. On Visual Studio (I can't check as I am on a Mac right now): Go to your project options, probably under the `Library` or also `General`tab  you can find the `Target Frameworks`. On VS, it probably won't show the profile number though.

Comment: I only found in VS that target is .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: You are adding this code to a PCL project, right? Or is this placed in a shared project or platform project? That would explain why you would need a NuGet package to make it work.

Comment: @Uros Tim is wrong. You should delete your question because your problem had nothing to do with the issue you mentioned, but was a configuration error of yours

Comment: I would like to delete this question, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Dbl, I thought it would be beneficial for reference. There should be a link to delete underneath the tags of your question between 'edit' and 'flag'.

Comment: Someone who gets here through google will ask a question similar to "How to implement progressable image upload in Xamarin" Does finding out that the OP forgot to reference a nuget package help him? Most certainly not. If it explains how to do it, it's a whole different story.